# How to change data in a Material Data Table with a button (Angular)

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I have an Angular Material Data Table that I created using ng generate @angular/material:material-table --name=BHTable.

I am trying to test how to dynamically change the contents of the table at runtime. In order to do this I want to create a button that clears the table by setting the datasource array to empty.

In my datasource.ts I have a function I added to change the datasource of the table.

```
public UpdateData(IncomingData: BhTableItem[]){
  this.data = IncomingData;
  }
```

When I press the button I made it calls a function in my normal (not datasource) components.ts which has this code.

```
  public UpdateTest(){

  this.dataSource.UpdateData([]);

  }
```

This should update the dataSource in the table, and change the contents of the table. However, when I press the button nothing happens.... I have read many different posts trying to figure this out but I have not gotten it to work. I think the answer has something to do with my method not firing the observable to update the table, but I am not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I forgot to mention. When I put my line into ngOnInit it looks like it works to change the contents of the table on page load. I want this same functionality, but for it to happen when I press the button.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new BhTableDataSource();
  this.dataSource.UpdateData([]);
  }
```

HTML since it was asked for.

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table class="full-width-table" matSort aria-label="Elements">
    <!-- Id Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Id</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.id}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.name}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator
      [length]="dataSource?.data.length"
      [pageIndex]="0"
      [pageSize]="50"
      [pageSizeOptions]="[25, 50, 100, 250]">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>

<button (click)="UpdateTest()"> Clear Table </button>
```

Comment: Show your HTML. Better share a stackbiltz

Comment: You should share a stackblitz, we can't see where you are connecting your data source to the table.

Comment: I don't know what a stackblitz is.. How do I do that?
Edit: Google is helping me with this.